# How to set customview in layout in android

Tags: android

Here is activity and with in this activity only created one custom view

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MyCustomDrawableView myCustomDrawableView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     myCustomDrawableView = new MyCustomDrawableView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myCustomDrawableView = (MyCustomDrawableView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
}

public class MyCustomDrawableView extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable myDrawable;

    public MyCustomDrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;
        int width = 100;
        int height = 100;

        myDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        myDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74fA23);
        myDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        myDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    }
}
```

then in layout create customview as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.mobiloitte.sampleapp.MainActivity.MyCustomDrawableView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

here i'm getting class not found exception

```
10-20 13:00:33.594: E/AndroidRuntime(542): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobiloitte.sampleapp.MainActivity.MyCustomDrawableView
```

pls help

Comment: Keep the MyCustomDrawableView in a seperate class file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Better is to use separate class (should not be an inner class) for custom view.*

For your current problem, try with

```
<com.mobiloitte.sampleapp.MainActivity$MyCustomDrawableView
```

---

Update for current issue `android.view.InflateException`

You need to add one more constructor for your custom view

```
public MyCustomDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet st) {
    super(context, st);
    // Do other initial tasks, like you did into MyCustomDrawableView(Context context).
}
```

Comment: Why static ? I've never used a static class for a view.

Comment: @StephaneMathis Removed that. If that view is going to be use into same activity only, then that is ok. But if you use that inner-version of view into another activity, it needs the instance of outer (activity class), so in that case better is to use static. This is only for inner version.

Comment: @PankajKumar error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) getting this problem with your answer

Comment: @Srikanth Then you must need to write separate view class, not an inner class.

Comment: @PankajKumar I tried by creating new class then also app crashing here is stacktrace http://pastebin.com/rTjPv5bQ

Comment: @Srikanth See my updated answer. You need to add one more constructor.

Comment: @PankajKumar Sorry for asking so many questions if you have time pls tell me. How can i know that i should add that constructor and parameters ,could you suggest doc related to constructors topic so that i wont ask stupid basic questions here.